# How can i fix 404 error of StompJS + WebSocket first "info"connect?

Tags: next.js, websocket, sockjs, stompjs

We are arguing 404 Error with WebSocket + StompJS first connect on "info" section.

Based on Next.js,JavaSpring with StompJS, SockJS, Websocket, We try to make real time chatting website.

But the first check "info" was returned 404 Error.
I learend that SockJS Client request "GET/Info" to get Server's basic info.
and then when Server supportWebSocket, Server response 200 response with isCookies needed or CORS Origin info .
After that we could connect and subscribe to Websocket.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjf6Y.png)

below pic is the Network/.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUBv7.png)

Why we event can't connect to the server for first check??

** FE code
PS. We are using Proxy on NExt.js

```
useEffect(() => {
        const socket = new SockJS('/ws', null, {transports: ["websocket", "xhr-streaming", "xhr-polling"]});
        const client = new Stomp.Client({
            webSocketFactory: () => socket,
            debug: (str) => {
                console.log(`debg: ${str}`)
            },
            onConnect: () => {
                console.log("=== connect Success === ");
            },
            onStompError: (frame) => {
                console.error('Broker reported error: ' + frame.headers['message']);
                console.error('Additional details: ' + frame.body);
            },
        });

        client.activate();

        return () => {client.deactivate();}

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])



//Proxy setting : next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
    async rewrites(){
        return {
            beforeFiles: [
                {
                    source:"/ws/:path",
                    destination: "https://server.farmingsoon.site/ws/:path",
                }
            ]
        }
    },
....
```

** BE Code

1. WebsocketConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/sub");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/pub");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("https://farmingsoon.vercel.app", "http://localhost:3000")
                .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

2. WebConfig.

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private  final AuthenticationInterceptor authenticationInterceptor;
    private final List<String> excludePointList = Arrays.asList();

    private final List<String> addEndPointList = Arrays.asList("/api/**");

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOriginPatterns("*") 
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS" , "PATCH")
                        .exposedHeaders("accessToken", "refreshToken");
                
            }
        };
    }
```

Please give us advice.

We try to change the WebSocketConfig from

```
etAllowedOrigins("*")
```

to

```
.setAllowedOriginPatterns("https://farmingsoon.vercel.app", "http://localhost:3000")
.withSockJS();
```

.